# Scanning for BLE devices using ios8 and cordova plugins

Tags: ios, cordova, bluetooth, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework

I am building an ios app using the ionic framework (cordova based), and am struggling to find a heart rate device (Wahoo Tickr) using a number of different cordova plugins.

The plugin I have looked at most closely is [cordova-plugin-ble-central](https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central). On device ready (`$ionicPlatform.ready`) I check to see if bluetooth is enabled using `ble.isEnabled()`. I get a successful result from this.

I then run `ble.scan([],10,successCallback, errorCallback)` but no devices are found. In fact, neither the success or error callbacks seem to be made. Running through XCode on my iPhone5 (running ios8), I see the following logs

```
2015-03-12 16:01:27.171 health[2893:1320748] scan
2015-03-12 16:02:27.173 health[2893:1320748] stopScanTimer
```

..which I have found are logged out from the plugin's BLECentralPlugin.m file.

I have also tried using the [BluetoothSerial](https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial) plugin, and [BluetoothLE](https://github.com/randdusing/BluetoothLE), but neither appear to find my device.

My device is found correctly in other apps (RunKeeper, Wahoo Fitness).

I was wondering if anyone had encountered this issue, and if so if they had managed to solve it or not. I feel that I am missing a step, but as Bluetooth is enabled and the plugin methods are accessed successfully I am just unsure how to proceed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your heart rate monitor is connected to a client, it won't be advertising so you won't see it while scanning.

Try using [LightBlue](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightblue-bluetooth-low-energy/id557428110?mt=8) on your phone. If LightBlue can see the heart rate monitor, your Cordova app running cordova-plugin-ble-central should be able to see it.

If LightBlue can't see the heart rate monitor, un-pair it from your phone and try again.